# Why is a desktop Java app using an old JRE?

Tags: macos, java, jre

In trying to comply with IT policy I've (I thought) removed all old versions of Java JREs and JDKs from OSX. `java -version` returns 1.7.0_51 and the Java Control Panel in System Settings also reports build 1.7.0_51.

Yet when I open up the app DeltaWalker, it sends an HTTP request to check for new versions and includes the header `User-Agent: Java/1.7.0_40`, which of course trips our organization's vulnerability detection system.

1. Why isn't DeltaWalker using the most recent version?
2. How can I find out what JRE an app like this or Eclipse/PhpStorm is using?
3. How can I track down this older JRE, and will deleting it break these apps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Keltari mentioned, many apps bundle their own Java version along with the application because it saves them from relying on your installed Java which they know nothing about.

You can open the DeltaWalker application in Finder to see that this is what is happening here. (I did this with a new copy of the DeltaWalker [dmg](https://s3.amazonaws.com/deltawalker/DeltaWalker-1.9.9.6_64.dmg), but yours should be the same).  Find the DeltaWalker "Application", Ctrl-click or right-click on it, and choose "Show Package Contents".  Navigate to `Contents\PlugIns\jre\Contents\Home\` to see the version of Java that is being used by the application.  You can go to this path in a Terminal window, go into the `bin` folder, and run `java -version` to confirm that it is the same version you are seeing in the User-Agent. (I can't check this myself, given that I am actually picking apart the application using 7-zip on a Windows computer.)

It is theoretically possible to just replace this Java version with a newer one, but I would hesitate to do that, given how tightly tied-together application components may be and given that DeltaWalker bundles many other dependencies along with it (helper executables and JAR plugins) which may also have issues.

If you are not using the most recent version of the application, you should update it if you can.  If you can't, or if the most recent version is still too old, you should contact [Deltopia Support](http://www.deltopia.com/support/).

Comment: I keep forgetting OSX apps are plain old browsable directories.

Answer (score 3):

I dont know about your apps or Macs, however Im sure it is similar to Windows.

Some applications will include their own Java version in the install.  Usually, this is done because they havent tested it with a newer version of Java and cannot guarantee their app works with a newer version.  Or, its possible, their app isnt compatible with a newer version of Java.

Check whatever launches your app and see if it specifically launches an older version.  You can try removing that launcher or editing it so it uses the newest version, however it may break the app.

I would check your apps support forums for more information.